# How to change the background color of the Chakra UI Toast component?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, toast, chakra-ui

I use Chakra UI and I have several Toast components in my application. They have a blue background color by default since they have `status="info"`.

How can I change the background color of all the toasts with `status="info"`? And I want to keep all other default styles (width, position etc.), need to change only color.

Answer (score 14):

The [`Toast`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/toast) component uses [`Alert`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/alert) under the hood.

`Alert` [maps the `status` prop to a color scheme](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/b983e4ceb7c1e794c2b901ce16f12016836d40d6/packages/alert/src/alert.tsx#L17-L22). This color scheme is [used in the theme definition](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/b983e4ceb7c1e794c2b901ce16f12016836d40d6/packages/theme/src/components/alert.ts#L75-L83) to define the background color.

By default, `status="info"` maps to `blue` and the `subtle` variant is used.

**EDIT (Chakra >= 2.0)**: Toast now uses the `solid` variant by default. In the following solution, replace `subtle` with `solid` to modify the default appearance.

Hence you would need add an override like this to your [theme definition](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/customize-theme):

```
import { theme as origTheme, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react"

const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Alert: {
      variants: {
        subtle: (props) => { // only applies to `subtle` variant
          const { colorScheme: c } = props
          if (c !== "blue") {
            // use original definition for all color schemes except "blue"
            return origTheme.components.Alert.variants.subtle(props)
          }
          return {
            container: {
              bg: `${c}.500`, // or literal color, e.g. "#0984ff"
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Color variables like `blue.500` are read from the [color definitions](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/theme#colors).

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of Chakra, Toasts are indeed using Alerts under the hood but they have switched to using the solid variant of Alert from subtle. Styling the solid variant of Alert will style your Toast.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own toast component wrapper like follow

```
import { Flex, Heading, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React from 'react';

const BaseAlert = (props) => {
  const { title, details, ...style } = props;

  return (
    <Flex
      flexDirection="column"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      {...style}
      py={4}
      px={4}
      borderLeft="3px solid"
      borderRight="3px solid"
      borderColor={`${style.colorScheme}.700`}
      bgColor={`${style.colorScheme}.100`}
    >
      <Heading
        as="h4"
        fontSize="md"
        fontWeight="500"
        color={`${style.colorScheme}.800`}
      >
        {props.title}
      </Heading>
      {props.details ? (
        <Text color={`${style.colorScheme}.800`}>{props.details}</Text>
      ) : null}
    </Flex>
  );
};

export const ErrorAlert = (props) => {
  return <BaseAlert colorScheme="red" {...props} />;
};
```

And use it like that

```
 toast({
    render: () => (
       <ErrorAlert
          title="Impossible d\'ajouter un nouveau moyen de paiement"
          details="Veuillez ressayer ou nous contacter"
       />
     ),
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

in extendTheme you have to change style of Alert. this is my solution and it worked.

```
const theme = extendTheme(
  {
    
    components: {
      Alert: {
          variants: {
            "left-accent": (props:any) => {
              const { status } = props
              return {
                container: {
                  ...theme.components.Alert.variants?.["left-accent"](props).container,
                  bg: `${status}.300`, 
                },
              }
            }
          }
   
      }
    }
  },
```