# How to change the background color of the Chakra UI Progress component?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

The same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531448/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-chakra-ui-toast-component), but for Progress instead of Toast. Extending the theme's Progress component does nothing, so I thought this component also uses another component, like how the Toast uses Alert, but I couldn't find anything about this.
This doesn't work for Progress: (but it works for other components, like Button or Alert)

```
const customTheme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Progress: {
      baseStyle: {
        bg: '#d4f3e7'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specifically target `filledTrack` (or just `track` if you'd like to style the background of the progress bar), because `<Progress>` is a [multipart component](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/component-style#styling-multipart-components).

```
const customTheme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Progress: {
      baseStyle: {
        filledTrack: {
          bg: '#d4f3e7'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but what I really need is for the background to change when the theme changes. With other components I could give it a function that uses the mode() function, but with Progress and its filledTrack, the filled Track disappears even if the function is as simple as () => ({ bg: '#1e9d6a' })

Comment: I managed to do it, it seems like you have to overwrite the basestyle of every part with a function to work

Comment: Or most likely the function just had to be a PartsStyleFunction<typeof progressAnatomy>